# datetime.date.today() in Django (Dash app)

Tags: python, django, datetime, plotly-dash, python-datetime

I have a Plotly Dash app running in Django using the `django-plotly-dash` package. (https://django-plotly-dash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

The app is live here: https://www.sunfire.xyz/data/tca

There is a date picker on the dashboard, and the code for the element is this:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
```

```
        html.Div([
            dcc.DatePickerRange(
                id='date-picker-range',
                min_date_allowed=date(2020, 10, 21),
                max_date_allowed=date.today(),
                initial_visible_month=date.today(),
                start_date=date.today() - timedelta(days=7),
                end_date=date.today(),
                display_format='DD/MM/YYYY',
            ),
        ], className="plotly-datepicker"),
```

The `max_date_allowed` and the default `end_date` should both be `datetime.date.today()` (which is 1st November as I'm typing this), however it seems  like `today()` is returning the day that the django application was started.

In fact, right now it's weirdly setting `max_date_allowed` to 31st October, but `end_date` is 30th Oct.
If I restart the server it works correctly, and will display 1st November.

How do I get `date.today()` to correctly display today's date when the application is running for multiple days?

FYI the `views.py` file for this app is importing the Dash App `from .dashapps import tca_log_plotter`

Comment: no sure if this is actually the issue here; but since `date.today()` returns the *local date*, the code will give you the dates depending on the machine the code runs on.

Comment: The server is running on UTC, and the in settings.py django is also set to UTC, which is the same as my local time. So it should be UTC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the code creating this Plotly Dash component is only being executed once, when the module is loaded (i.e. "the day that the django application was started"). You don't show where this instantiation is happening so there's not enough information to identify the precise cause. Perhaps you've factored out this component definition into a module-level variable for reuse? In any case, the solution is to make sure that the datepicker code gets called on every request.

Also, use Django's [`localdate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localdate) function, not `date.today()`. The latter does not take Django's settings (like `TIME_ZONE`) into account.

Comment: Ah I did think this might be the problem but I thought the Dash App would be called every time someone loaded the page. I guess not though.

Comment: Found some documentation on your suggestion which solves my issue: https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates Thanks!